# Should I delete an Answer if the question was edited (not by the user) to ask a different question?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

Recently I provided an answer to a question that was - let's be honest - not written that well and fairly vague. I did my best to interpret the answer in the best way I could, but an editor came along and changed the grammar and phrasing around of the question so much that my answer went from helpful to incorrect. I've since received 2-3 down votes in addition to 3-4 up votes (it was standing at +1 at the time of deletion, I don't have +/- viewing yet).

My question is, should I:

1. Stand firm with my answer based on my interpretation and try to speak with the editor to come to a consensus on what the intent of the question was before translation/editing
2. Delete my answer
3. Leave my answer and perhaps continue to receive down votes
4. Otherwise?

I tend to jump into questions quickly to try to help people out in a reasonable timeframe, so this has happened more than just this one occasion. It's as much of a hypothetical as a specific inquiry, hence the discussion tag. What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Never answer vague questions. They eventually get closed and deleted, so your hard work is lost. There are tons of questions, find a better one to answer. If you really want to contribute that answer, either edit the question into shape before answering via a suggested edit, or write a good, clear question yourself with a self answer. Writing a good, clear question with a self answer is far better than answering vague, unclear questions.

Comment: I think you are right. I felt like I had a good understanding but given its ambiguity I should have expected it would be edited by someone. I didn't think it needed editing to give a solid answer, but that doesn't mean someone else wouldn't feel the same way.

Answer (score 4):

I'd roll back the edit.

If the editor changed the question so much they invalidated the existing answers (yours in this case) then it's an invalid edit.

What you perhaps should have done was to either leave a comment asking the OP for clarification or edited the question yourself before answering.

Comment: Because the question was ambiguous and I don't know the true intent of the asker, I can't say for sure the edit didn't reflect the real intent better than how I perceived the question. I think it's more my fault for answering a vague question. This would certainly be the correct answer if the question was straightforward before and changed to something different.