# Is it wrong to delete an irrelevant answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Someone posted a query regarding web development (HTML, CSS stuff) and the question looked like it needed a bit more furnishing. But, anyway I went ahead to answer it as it seemed okay. I put like about half hour or so to get the answer code for the required result ready and posted it away. About some minutes later, I saw that the OP had added a few restrictions to the question about what can/cannot be used. That made my answer unusable for the OP's use-case and maybe she/he down-voted the answer with comment to refer the answer restrictions. I did not know how to fix it with the added restrictions so I deleted the answer since it was not acceptable (and also to avoid more down-votes).

Later, I came back to SO to see that someone had down-voted many of my well-received posts (maybe the same person went to my profile to see all the things on SO I posted) for no reason/explanation. Was anything wrong with deleting the answer in particular? What is the preferred thing to do on SO for such future-irrelevant posts?

Comment: Please add a link to the question.

Comment: Or maybe it was a different user the one making the downvotes. Correlation != Causation.

Comment: I think the answer here also applies to your case: [Should I delete an Answer if the question was edited (not by the user) to ask a different question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269207/2745495)

Comment: The biggest problem here is that you did not listen to your gut. *"the question looked like it needed a bit more furnishing."* -> right there. See? You have the gift. A shame you chose to ignore it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several things going on here:

There is nothing intrinsically bad in deleting an answer that has no value. If you post an answer and you discover it is wrong, go ahead and delete it if you can. We want only good quality answers around.

However...

> About some minutes later, I saw that the OP had added a few restrictions to the question about what can/cannot be used. That made my answer unusable for the OP's use-case

If the answer was made irrelevant because the **question was changed**, then the appropriate thing is to **rollback changes to the question that invalidate existing answers**.

At the same time, you say:

> and the question looked like it needed a bit more furnishing. But, anyway I went ahead to answer [...]

Maybe you answered an unclear question to begin with. In these cases, I have less sympathy about changes to the question invalidating your answer. If this was the case, next time, try to help the OP to bring their question up to scratch **before** posting an answer.

And then you mention downvotes:

> Later, I came back to SO to see that someone had down-voted many of my well-received posts (maybe the same person went to my profile to see all the things on SO I posted)

Or maybe someone else did. I see only two downvotes in your profile, currently. Maybe those were some kind of revenge vote by this or other user, or maybe they are completely unrelated. It's better not to jump to conclusions prematurely. Two stray downvotes, even if they are cast in anger, are better shrugged off. We have all received some of those. It's sad, but it happens. If the pattern continues for several days, then it's time to worry and raise a mod-flag.

Finally:

> [downvoted] for no reason/explanation.

Do not expect users posting comments explaining their votes. Those are [not required](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436), and are actually discouraged.